# Profiling .war files

Tags: java, apache-flex, tomcat, profiler

I have a multi-threaded application that I have deployed on a Tomcat server via a .war (it includes both Java and Adobe Flex), and for some reason it is taking 100% of a cpu (50% on a 2 core, 25% on a 4 core, etc). As far as I can tell, I don't have incorrect polling or while(trues), and I'm having a hard time finding the problem.

In the past I've profiled C/C++ code and it's very easy to see "oh this function got called x many times and is taking up X% of time." Is there some utility that does something similar? The project can't be run from the IDE (and so I'm assuming can't be profiled in a normal way), it has to be deployed via .war. The project is in Netbeans/FlashBuilder, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Attach with jvisualvm in the JDK and use CPU profiling.

Comment: Instead of profiling, you can use code coverage (e.g. Coberture). It counts how many times each method/line/branch was executed.

Comment: Thorbjørn, the problem is that it's actually not a java application I can open (i.e. Tomcat is taking up very little). Plug-container.exe (for firefox or whatever) is the thing that's eating CPU.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to clarify what the problem is.  Since most of the question focuses on how you deployed the app the server, I (and others) assumed you had a server issue.  But, since you're worried about the Firefox plugin container taking up RAM; it is clearly a client issue with your Flash/Flex application.  I'm not sure why the project can't be run from the IDE.  But, I suggest you go back to the source code and use the Flash Builder Profiler to examine the Flex app for memory leaks.

Comment: If plug-container.exe is eating up the CPU, then you must be talking about a client-side problem which will not have anything to do with Tomcat. It probably isn't even Java code that is the problem: it's probably the Adobe Flex program that the client is downloading and executing.